# Aligning vdots with terms in a system of equations

Tags: align

I am attempting to write a system of linear equations that looks like this:

```
A_{11}x_1 + A_{12}x_2 + \cdots + A_{1n}x_n = y_1
A_{21}x_1 + A_{22}x_2 + \cdots + A_{2n}x_n = y_2
\vdots      \vdots               \vdots      \vdots
A_{m1}x_1 + A_{m2}x_2 + \cdots + A_{mn}x_n = y_m
```

where the vdots are centered on the terms rather than the equal sign. Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&A_{11}x_1& + &A_{12}x_2& + \cdots + &A_{1n}x_n& = &y_1& \\
&A_{21}x_1& + &A_{22}x_2& + \cdots + &A_{2n}x_n& = &y_2& \\
&\vdots&  &\vdots& &\vdots& &\vdots& \\
&A_{m1}x_1& + &A_{m2}x_2& + \cdots + &A_{mn}x_n& = &y_m& \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Anyone have an elegant solution?

EDIT. Here is a second attempt, using the better-suited `array` environment. It looks better, but still unnatural.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
A_{11}x_1 & + & A_{12}x_1 & + & \cdots & + & A_{1n}x_n & = & y_1 \\
A_{21}x_1 & + & A_{22}x_2 & + & \cdots & + & A_{2n}x_n & = & y_2 \\
\vdots    &   & \vdots    &   &        &   & \vdots    &   & \vdots \\
A_{m1}x_1 & + & A_{m2}x_2 & + & \cdots & + & A_{mn}x_n & = & y_m \\
\end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to have the vdots aligned like this but make the equations look normal?

Comment: An `array` environment?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora That works better, but it still doesn't look right. See edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest the following modification:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{*{9}{@{}c@{}}}
A_{11}x_1 & {}+{} & A_{12}x_1 &{}+{} & \cdots & {}+{} & A_{1n}x_n & {}\mathrel{=}{} & y_1 \\
A_{21}x_1 & + & A_{22}x_2 & + & \cdots & + & A_{2n}x_n & = & y_2 \\
\vdots    &   & \vdots    &   &        &   & \vdots    &   & \vdots \\
A_{m1}x_1 & + & A_{m2}x_2 & + & \cdots & + & A_{mn}x_n & = & y_m \\
\end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend you use the a `\makebox` to get the `\vdots` centered and use the `alignat` environment to do multiple alignment points:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\MyVdots}[1][$A_{22}x_n$]{\makebox[\widthof{#1}]{$\vdots$}}%
\newcommand*{\Ph}{\hphantom{{}+{}}}%
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{5}
    &A_{11}x_1 &&{}+ A_{12}x_2  &&{}+ \cdots &&{}+ A_{1n}x_n && = y_1 \\
    &A_{21}x_1 &&{}+ A_{22}x_2  &&{}+ \cdots &&{}+ A_{2n}x_n && = y_2 \\
    &\MyVdots  &&\Ph \MyVdots   &&           &&\Ph  \MyVdots &&\Ph \MyVdots[$y_1$] \\
    &A_{m1}x_1 &&{}+ A_{m2}x_2  &&{}+ \cdots &&{}+ A_{mn}x_n && = y_m \\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two TABstacks, one with a lesser space around the `\vdots`, the other with a greater space.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[\TABbinary
\let\svvdots\vdots\def\vdots{\protect\raisebox{-3pt}{$\svvdots$}}
\tabbedCenterstack{
A_{11}x_1 & + & A_{12}x_1 & + & \cdots & + & A_{1n}x_n & = & y_1 \\
A_{21}x_1 & + & A_{22}x_2 & + & \cdots & + & A_{2n}x_n & = & y_2 \\
\vdots    &   & \vdots    &   &        &   & \vdots    &   & \vdots \\
A_{m1}x_1 & + & A_{m2}x_2 & + & \cdots & + & A_{mn}x_n & = & y_m \\
}\]
\[\TABbinary
\let\svvdots\vdots\def\vdots{\protect\raisebox{3pt}{$\svvdots$}}
\tabbedShortstack{
A_{11}x_1 & + & A_{12}x_1 & + & \cdots & + & A_{1n}x_n & = & y_1 \\
A_{21}x_1 & + & A_{22}x_2 & + & \cdots & + & A_{2n}x_n & = & y_2 \\
\vdots    &   & \vdots    &   &        &   & \vdots    &   & \vdots \\
A_{m1}x_1 & + & A_{m2}x_2 & + & \cdots & + & A_{mn}x_n & = & y_m \\
}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]